# Can I use ob_clean() without ob_start() before?

Tags: php, output-buffering, ob-start

I am not used to `ob_*` functions and I began by reading the documentation.
I would like to use [`ob_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) in a **method** but the documentation says:

> The output buffer must be started by `ob_start()` with `PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE` flag. Otherwise **ob_clean()** will not work.

However I tried *(just to see how it "wouldn't work")*:

```
echo 'a';
ob_clean();
echo 'b';
```

Which outputs `b`. Everything seems working fine here, but following the documentation, it shouldn't, should it ?

- Is `ob_start()` mandatory for `ob_*` functions ?
- Is there a variable (in the **php.ini** for example) which default value allows to ommit `ob_start()` ?
- How should I understand *"**ob_clean()** will not work"* ? What should I expect ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that yes, you have to turn on output buffering before you can use `ob_clean`. However, it is possible that you have output buffering enabled for all files through the `output_buffering` ini parameter (see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php)). The way to check for this is through [`ob_get_level()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php):

```
echo ob_get_level();
```

If the result is non-zero, output buffering is enabled.

If you do use `ob_clean()` without buffering enabled, you should see an error similar to this:

> Notice: ob_clean() [ref.outcontrol]: failed to delete buffer. No
>   buffer to delete. in [file-path]

Comment: Then I could verify if output buffering is enabled using `ob_get_level()` but does calling `ob_start()` after an output will allow me to erase this output using `ob_clean()` ?

Comment: `ob_clean()` will only remove the output after its matching `ob_start()`. So any output before an `ob_start()` will not be affected by the `ob_clean()`.

Comment: If output buffering is enabled automatically, calling `ob_clean()` will remove any output before that point, as you saw in your test case.

Comment: I am exporting the content via csv when I have used @ob_clean();
 @ob_start() then I got the random characters in the export CSV file and when I have removed those functions then export work fines then what is the problem behind it?

Comment: @BhavinThummar without seeing your code and data its hard to tell. You should ask a question.